# How to deal with irregular date formats or date error in R?

Tags: r, date

I am reading a csv file in R and it has date column.I am using

```
as.Date(dat$date, format ="%d-%m-%Y")
```

But i am getting dates in

```
0012-02-14
```

with the year 2012 described as 0012. How to deal with this error.
I also tried lubridate package but no results

```
col1     col2       policydate
112345   Renew      02/28/2012
156566   Not Renew  03/25/2010
895414   Renew      10/01/2006
```

Something like this.

Comment: Can you show some of the input data that produces this output?

Comment: share the reproducible example so we can see how your date looks originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
as.Date(dat$date, format ="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2012-02-28" "2010-03-25" "2006-10-01"
```

Your problem was related to the use of - instead / and the reversal of days and month in the format code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the format as per your date format which is month/day/Year.

```
data <- data.frame(Date=c("02/28/2012","03/25/2010"))
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format ="%m/%d/%Y")
```

**Result**

```
"2012-02-28" "2010-03-25"
```

You can always follow this style guide to format your date.

[image: Date Format Style Guide]